# Writing Aspects For Reactive Pipelines

Tags: java, rx-java, aop, spring-aop, project-reactor

I am writing Aspects for methods that return promises. Consider the following method:

```
public Mono<Stream> publishToKafka(Stream s) {
    //publishToKafka is asynchronous
    return Mono.just(s).flatMap(worker::publishToKafka);
}
```

I want to cache if the publish was successful or not. Since this is a cross-cutting concern, an Aspect looks like the best design. Here's my Aspect for it.

```
@Around("@annotation....")
public Object cache() {
    //get the data to cache from the annotation
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    cache.cache("key","data");
    return result;
}
```

Now since `publishToKafka` is asynchronous, the target method returns as soon as the thread switch happens and `cache.cache()` is called. This is not what I want. What I want is that the result should be cached iff the event was successfully published to Kafka. The following advice works.

```
@Around("@annotation....")
public <T extends Stream<T>> Mono<T> cache() {
    //get the data to cache from the annotation
    return ((Mono<T>)pjp.proceed()).doOnNext(a -> cache.cache(key, data));
}
```

I want to understand what's going on here. Does this happen during the assembly time of the pipeline? Or during the execution time (`pjp.proceed()` returns a promise) to which my advice adds the `doOnNext` operator?

I need to understand assembly vs. execution time in the context of this example.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot this basic SO etiquette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Spring AOP and AspectJ aspects are always executed synchronously in the same thread as the intercepted joinpoint. Thus, if your intercepted method returns immediately and the return value is something like a promise, a future or nothing (void) in combination with a callback, you cannot expect to magically get the asynchronous result in the aspect's advice. You do need to make the aspect aware of the asynchronous situation.

Having said that, I also want to mention that I never used reactive programming before, I only know the concept. From what I see in your advice, the solution should work, but one thing is not so nice: You make the advice return a **new** `Mono` instance [returned by your `doOnNext(..)` call](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-). Maybe it would be cleaner to return the **original** `Mono` you get from `proceed()` after having registered your caching callback on it, just so as to avoid any side-effects.

I don't know what else to explain, the situation is pretty clear. Feel free to ask directly related follow-up questions if my explanation does not suffice.

Comment: "Maybe it would be cleaner to return the original Mono you get from proceed() after having registered your caching callback on it, just so as to avoid any side-effects.". I didn't get it. I am registering the caching callback in the doOnNext operator. Could you please explain a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: You didn't read the Javadoc link I provided. It clearly explains that `doOnNext()` returns a new mono instance, i.e. not the original object. You then pass it on as the result of your intercepted method execution.

Comment: @kriegaex Is `((Mono<T>)pjp.proceed())` a blocking code. I am using the same ( without. doOnnext) and I have a blocking method being run on a separate threadpool inside my pointcut method. And in this case the time taken considers the time taken by the blocking event also. Now I want the total time to not include the time for the execution of blocking event. How can I acheive that ?

Comment: @javaGroup456, I think you already asked a related question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64372230/1082681). I think it is better to wait for an answer there than to hijack this question.