# Spring webflux - AOP How to use aspect such that it is processed before the call to blocking operation( pushed onto a background thread)

Tags: aop, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have  Restful application written on spring webflux.

In my use case, I have to call a blocking operation that will do some processing. The blocking call is being run in a separate thread pool. ( done by calling the blocking operation inside a callable)
I have added aspect on the method `myServiceMethod` in which a `Flatmap` does some transformation on it.
Now the purpose of adding aspect here was to capture the total time taken by the rest api ( excluding the time taken by  `blockMethod`).
But the implementation is somehow being processed in a way that it only logs the data after processing the blocking code.
What can be fixed here so as to make sure aspect processes before the `blockMethod` is called.

```java
private Mono<Result> myServiceMethod(String any1, String any2) {
  return myWebClient.get()
    .uri("http://I-just-wsnt-log-the-round-trip-time-fro-api-call.com/").bodyToMono(Result)
    .flatMap(someThing -> myCallable(someThing));
}

private Mono<Result> myCallable(int value) {
  return Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockMethod(value))
    .subscribeOn(this.scheduler);
}
```

*Note : The above code could be a bit faulty, but hope it okay as long as it conveys the idea.
And My aspect code using pointcut is as follows :

```java
@Pointcut("execution(public * MyClass.myServiceMethod(..))")
public void custompoint() {}

@Around("custompoint()")
public Mono<String> calculateTimeAdStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
  return Mono.just(1)
    .flatMap(logTime(joinPoint));
}

// logging time taken by calling ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed
private Mono<String> logTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
  Instant start = Instant.now();
  return ((Mono<Result>)joinPoint.proceed()).flatMap(() -> {
    String log = Instant.now().toMillis() - start);
    return Mono.just(log);
  });
}
```

My question is how can I change this by making sure that the logged time is not including the time take by `blockMethod`.

### Update

I have tried some things with context. Adding my changes here. But seems that my changes made in the context are not reaching the advice where I call `jointpoint.proceed`.

```java
private Mono<Result> myServiceMethod(String any1, String any2) {
  return myWebClient.get()
    .uri("http://I-just-want-log-the-round-trip-time-for-api-call.com/").bodyToMono(Result)
    .flatMap(someThing -> myCallable(someThing))
    .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("timeTakenTest", 56000L ));
}
```

Here is the code of the advice method. Here the value of key`"timeTakenTest"` is always 0 (default) when printed. so clearly the entry I added in the subscriberContext in the executed method is not available here.

The `.replacing` getOrDefault`with`get` gives error as below. so clearly its either never being added to context or in the middle somewhere context is getting recreated causing this issue.

```java
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context does not contain key: timeTakenTest
```

```java
// logging time taken by calling ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed
private Mono<String> logTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
  Instant start = Instant.now();
  return ((Mono<Result>)joinPoint.proceed())
  .zipWith(Mono.subscriberContext() 
                .map(c -> (Long)c.getOrDefault("timeTakenTest", 0L))).flatMap(responseData -> {
             System.out.println("Subscription time registered is : " + responseData.getT2());
     //something done here.
  });
}
```

I think I have followed the documentation good.
It even says in the document :

> subscriberContext(Context) merges the Context you provide and the Context from downstream (remember, the Context is propagated from the bottom of the chain towards the top). This is done through a call to putAll, resulting in a new Context for upstream.

Please suggest.

Reference : https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context.read

Comment: placing something on its on scheduler does not mean that only that single method is processed asynchronous on its own thread pool.  What you actually do is that you tell the server, that when someone subscribes they should use threads from the assigned scheduler and not from the standard event loop. So that ENTIRE request is run on its own thread pool. `onSubscribe` the entire scheduler is used for the entire subscription.

Comment: so what you are basically saying is that you want to log the time of a request excluding a single method. Well then you have to time the entire request, and then time only that specific method, and then subtract the method time from the total time.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I was thinking if switching the `((Mono<Result>)joinPoint.proceed())` statement  with just `joinPoint.proceed()` could help here ?  the following flatmap code would also be removed in that case and return type too wiuld be change to void maybe.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf  On your last comment, How can I calculate the time taken by entire request and time taken by specific method so that its available in that same method. If I use a separate aspect  to calc time for the specific method then how will I be able to map that whether 2 calculated times  belong to same request ?

Comment: By placing them in the context

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Could you please explain with an example ( may be some code snippet or just some elaboration)   so that I can understand it better ?

Comment: no, you can instead read the reactor documentation about the context and what it is used for.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf  I tried with the context ( referred to documentation ) but seems like the data I entered in subscriberContext is not available when I try to read it from advice. please see my updates and suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: im guessing you are loosing the data in your cast, but im not sure